# TypeError: Cannot read property 'injector' of null after upgrading to Angular 2.0 final

Tags: unit-testing, testing, angular, typescript, angular2-testing

After upgrading from Angular 2 RC5 to 2.0 Final, I'm seeing the following errors when running my tests. I'm not sure what the problem is.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'injector' of null
    at TestBed._createCompilerAndModule (webpack:///Users/mraible/dev/ng2-demo/~/@angular/core/testing/test_bed.js:247:0 <- src/test.ts:20777:44)
    at TestBed._initIfNeeded (webpack:///Users/mraible/dev/ng2-demo/~/@angular/core/testing/test_bed.js:213:0 <- src/test.ts:20743:39)
    at TestBed.createComponent (webpack:///Users/mraible/dev/ng2-demo/~/@angular/core/testing/test_bed.js:297:0 <- src/test.ts:20827:14)
```

Here's an example of one of my tests:

```
import { MockSearchService } from '../shared/search/mocks/search.service';
import { EditComponent } from './edit.component';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing/test_bed';
import { SearchService } from '../shared/search/search.service';
import { MockRouter, MockActivatedRoute } from '../shared/search/mocks/routes';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

describe('Component: Edit', () => {
  let mockSearchService: MockSearchService;
  let mockActivatedRoute: MockActivatedRoute;
  let mockRouter: MockRouter;

  beforeEach(() => {
    mockSearchService = new MockSearchService();
    mockActivatedRoute = new MockActivatedRoute({'id': 1});
    mockRouter = new MockRouter();

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [EditComponent],
      providers: [
        {provide: SearchService, useValue: mockSearchService},
        {provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: mockActivatedRoute},
        {provide: Router, useValue: mockRouter}
      ],
      imports: [FormsModule]
    });
  });

  it('should fetch a single record', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EditComponent);

    let person = {name: 'Emmanuel Sanders', address: {city: 'Denver'}};
    mockSearchService.setResponse(person);

    fixture.detectChanges();
    // verify service was called
    expect(mockSearchService.getByIdSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1);

    // verify data was set on component when initialized
    let editComponent = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(editComponent.editAddress.city).toBe('Denver');

    // verify HTML renders as expected
    let compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector('h3').innerHTML).toBe('Emmanuel Sanders');
  });
});
```

For a pull request that demonstrates this issue, please see GitHub: https://github.com/mraible/ng2-demo/pull/4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing `import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing/test_bed';` to `import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';` solved this problem for me.